# Hiding a menu when the mouse is no longer over either the menu head OR the menu body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu and when mouse is over the parent element the menu body will appear now i want to hide the menu body only when mouse leave the menu head or mouse leave the menu body, but what i could get so far is, either the body disappear when mouse leave the menu head which will not allow the user to make selection from the menu body

```js
$(document).on("mouseover", '.menu-head', function() {
  $(this).find('a').addClass('filter-hover');
  $(this).find('span').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up' style='color:#aaa;'></i>");
  $(".menu-body").show();
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", '.menu-body', function() {
  $('.menu-head').find('a').removeClass('filter-hover');
  $('.menu-head').find('span').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down' style='color:#aaa;'></i>");
  $(".menu-body").hide();
});
```

```css
.menu-body {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-head">
  <ul class="attr-list">
    <li><a href="">Sole <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down "></i></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="">Sole Type <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down "></i></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="">Material <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down "></i></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="menu-body">
  <div class="attr-name filter-list">
    <ul class="attr-list">
      <li><a href="">Rubber</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Rubber</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Rubber</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Rubber</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Rubber</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Rubber</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

js code

```
first try...
$(function () {
        $('.menu-head').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('a').addClass('filter-hover');
            $(this).find('span').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up' style='color:#aaa;'></i>");
            $(".menu-body").show();
            //alert('enter');
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('a').removeClass('filter-hover');
            $(this).find('span').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down' style='color:#aaa;'></i>");
            $(".menu-body").hide();
        });
    });
```

The first try hide the menu-body when mouse is out of menu head, therefore can't make selection from menu body

```
second try...
$(document).on("mouseover", '.menu-head',function(){
        $(this).find('a').addClass('filter-hover');
        $(this).find('span').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up' style='color:#aaa;'></i>");
        $(".menu-body").show();
    });

    $(document).on("mouseleave", '.menu-body,function(){
        $('.menu-head').find('a').removeClass('filter-hover');
        $('.menu-head').find('span').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down' style='color:#aaa;'></i>");
        $(".menu-body").hide();
    });
```

the second try will show menu-body when mouse over menu-head but will only hide menu-body when mouse leave menu-body, so when mouse leave menu-head without entering menu-body them=n menu-body will be show, how can i make this work, i hope my question is clear, thanks for any help

i added this fiddle to clearly explain what i want, [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r7a9sey5/2/) and we can see that when we hover on the main menu the submenu appears but only when we hover on the sub menu will it disappear if we don't hover on the submenu it stays up here

Comment: your second try is working fine, check once

Comment: @Javascript_Lover thanks for your replay but second try is not working as expected because the menu-body will not be hide when mouse leave the menu-head without going through the menu body, so if a user hover on first menu and decided to leave  without hovering on the menu-body then the menu body will be display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By wrapping these two parts in a container and triggering the hide/show behavior based on that parent container, you don't have any complicated states to check. You can actually use the `li` elements in the menu-head as the wrappers since they can contain the link and the submenu.

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.menu', function(event) {
  $(this).children('.menu-body').stop().toggle(event.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

```css
.menu-body {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.menu-head>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-head">
  <ul class="attr-list">
    <li class="menu">
      <a href="">Sole <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down "></i></span></a>
      <div class="menu-body">
        <div class="attr-name filter-list">
          <ul class="attr-list">
            <li><a href="">Sole Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sole Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sole Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sole Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sole Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sole Menu Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
      <a href="">Sole Type <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down "></i></span></a>
      <div class="menu-body">
        <div class="attr-name filter-list">
          <ul class="attr-list">
            <li><a href="">Sole Type Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sole Type Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sole Type Menu Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu">
      <a href="">Material <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down "></i></span></a>
      <div class="menu-body">
        <div class="attr-name filter-list">
          <ul class="attr-list">
            <li><a href="">Material Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Material Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Material Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Material Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Material Menu Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, your approach is very good, but consider my example it has some setback, if i wrap the 2 element inside another element it works but when move over the parent element then all the submenu appears how can i make it such that when mouse over a particular element of the main menu i will show submenu related to it, you can see my jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/r7a9sey5/7/

Comment: Right, but the idea is to show you how to fix the issue, not write your code... I have adjusted this answer to remove the animation that was previously suggested. This solution now wraps your child `ul` submenus within the parent lists `li` elements. I think this should be pretty close to what you are looking for when handling multiple submenus.